# Tiered Parallel Execution w/ Failure Recovery in Jenkins

Tags: continuous-integration, hudson, jenkins

In the figure below, I want each level of jobs to run in parallel (as many as they can simultaneously on executors), and **IF** one arbitrary job fails, after fixing the problem I want the things to run normal again (as if the job didn't fail). I mean if the failed job is build successfully after fixing, I want the jobs at lower levels to start automatically.

I have seen that Build Flow Plugin cannot realize that. I hope someone has some brilliant ideas to share.

Thanks for your time.

[image]

For Further Clarification:

All the jobs at level x must be successful before all the jobs at level x+1. If some job at level x fails, I do not want any job at level x+1 to start. After fixing the the problem, re-run the job, and if it succeeds (and all the other at level x also have succeeded), then I want level x+1 to start building.

Answer (score 0):

Referencing your diagram, I'll restate the requirements of your question (to make sure I understand it).

1. At Level 1, you want all of the jobs to run in parallel (if possible)
2. At Level 2, you want all of the jobs to run in parallel
3. At Level 3, you want all of the jobs to run in parallel
4. Any successful build of a Level 1 job should cause all Level 2 jobs to build
5. Any successful build of a Level 2 job should cause all Level 3 jobs to build

My answer should work if you do *not* require "Any failure at Level 1 will prevent all Level 2 jobs from running."

I don't believe this will require any other plugins.  It just uses what is built into Jenkins.

- For each Level 1 job, configure a Post Build action of "Build other projects"

  - The projects to build should be all of your Level 2 jobs.  (The list should be comma separated list.)
  - Check "Trigger only if build succeeds"
- For each Level 2 job, configure a Post Build action of "Build other projects"

  - The projects to build should be all of your Level 3 jobs.

Comment: All the jobs at level x must go green **before** all the jobs at level x+1. And if some job at level x goes red, I do not want any job at level x+1 to start. After fixing the the problem, re-run the job, and if it goes green (and all the other at level x are also green), then I want level x+1 to start building. I hope you understand what I mean.